# Is there any mounting standard for prefilled liquid coolers?

Tags: desktop, case, cooling

I am trying to find and buy cheap computer case with 2 fan liquid cooler. Like this:

[image]

However, I've been having trouble finding cases that fit this description:

- With "liquid cooler" keywords I found liquid coolers, of course (mixed with cases).
- Often "liquid cooler" support means that case have holes for cooler, but no place for radiator.
- Often I've found cases with top 2 fans, but not enough space for the  cooler itself.

Is there some standard or abbreviation that identifies whether a case supports the installation of such coolers?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of modern tower cases (and many smaller cases) support at least a 240mm radiator with fans in some configuration. AFAIK, there is no standardized compatibility keyword; however, most manufacturers make it clear in their documentation what radiators are supported (both footprint and thickness.)

One useful tool is PCPartPicker. To check compatibility, you can start a new system build, add a radiator, then go to cases and with "Enable compatibility filter" checked, browse the list of cases.

[image]

If you have other constraints in mind, please post them so we can help get you a more specific recommendation.